# Select function(arg) from dual in Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

DB : Oracle

I am able to execute the following statement in both sql dev and sql plus:

```
select OUTPUT_DATA(123) from dual;
```

But when I try to execute this statement on Python, python crashes

```
if database == 'oracle':
    conn_str = 'Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=%s;User ID=%s;Password=%s;' % (dbserver, dbUID, dbPWD)    #oracle connection string
    try:
        conn = Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
        conn.Open(conn_str)
        conn.Execute(sqlCommand)
        conn.Close()
        result = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception('Failed to execute SQL with Excpetion: ' + str(e))
```

Below is a screenshot of the python error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 73, in execInThread
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 196, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncreq
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 431, in sync_request
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 379, in serve
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 337, in _recv
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\channel.py", line 50, in recv
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 166, in read
EOFError: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 148, in __getattribute__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncreq
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 429, in sync_request
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 229, in _send_request
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 224, in _send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\channel.py", line 69, in send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 176, in write
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 60, in __getattr__
EOFError: stream has been closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 196, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncreq
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 429, in sync_request
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 229, in _send_request
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 224, in _send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\channel.py", line 69, in send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 176, in write
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 60, in __getattr__
EOFError: stream has been closed
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: how did you write the `sqlCommand` ?

Comment: i just call my function with the db information and the sql statement:
run_sql_query("oracle", dbserver="XXX", dbUID="XXX", dbPWD="XXXX", sqlCommand='select output_data(123) from dual')

Comment: is this code crashing if you comment the line `conn.Execute(sqlCommand)` ?

Comment: it does not crash if the `conn.Execute(sqlCommand)` is commented out. Executing the below sql command crashes python
`select output_data(123) from dual` 

Executing `select sysdate from dual` works with no issue